# Communication between an Application class and Service in Android

Tags: android, android-service

I have a requirement where I have already extended an "Application" class in my Android Project.

eg:

```
  public class myApp extends Application implements
    myReceiver.Receiver {...}
```

Is it possible for me to communicate through a "Service" using my - "Message.obtain" or should I use other things? Please advice.

I also want to pass data to my Service which is a String/constant value. Can I do it like this :

```
 private void sendMsg(int arg1, int arg2) {  
        if (mBound) {  
            Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MyService.Hello,
                arg1, arg2);  
            try {  
                mService.send(msg);  
             } catch (RemoteException e) {  
                Log.e(TAG, "Error sending a message", e);  

             }  
         }  
     }
```

Comment: i think it is possible by using Handler and Messenger

Comment: you can also use a BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @GoranHoriamihail  In android broadcast receivers participates in interprocess communication. So it is not recommended to use in this case.

Comment: @ Komal gundavarapu If its a concern that other apps can intercept the broadcast then use LocalBroadcastManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html), and send a local broadcast, this way the data you are broadcasting won't leave your app, so don't need to worry about leaking private data.

Comment: Messenger is also used for inter process communication

Comment: @GoranHoriaMihail broadcastReceiver are heavy weight components ... in the above case it is not required. if there is no other alternative then we can go with broadCast

Comment: broadcastReceiver are heavy weight components - do you have a source/link for that compared with Messenger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: 
in the extends Application class create one inner class

```
private class MyMessageHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        Bundle bundelData = msg.getData();
        if (bundelData != null) {
            String mString = (String) bundelData.get(IConstants.HOME_SCREEN_LISTUPDATE);
            if (mString != null) {
             // your logic   
            }
        }
    }
```

starting the service by passing the Messenger

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, WatchService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra(IConstants.MYMESSAGE_HANDLER, new Messenger(new MyMessageHandler));
startService(serviceIntent);
```

in the service onStartCommand get the messenger

```
if (intent != null) {
Bundle mExtras = intent.getExtras();
if (mExtras != null) {
Messenger innrMessenger = (Messenger)mExtras.get(IConstants.MYMESSAGE_HANDLER);
}
}
```

if you want to send data from service to that class

```
Message message = Message.obtain();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(IConstants.HOME_SCREEN_LISTUPDATE, state);
message.setData(bundle);
innrMessenger.send(message);//get call back for handleMessage(Message msg)
```