# Passing a notification from my object to a service

Tags: android, media-player

I'm working in an app for android. I have a `Service` to manage the background process of streamming. Then I have an object `AudioPlayer` that manages the `MediaPlayer` instance and it get called from the service. But the problem I have is with the listener `onPrepared`, because it's within my `AudioPlayer` but I need that when it gets trigger send a message from my object `AudioPlayer` to my `Service`. Is it that possible?

I can try to put the logic of my `MediaPlayer` within `Service`, but I want to keep things decouple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible.For communication between service and fragment you can use
 1.BroadCast Receiver or 2.Messenger

Using messengers refer this link [Communication between an Application class and Service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794109/communication-between-an-application-class-and-service-in-android/27794342#27794342)

Comment: I already communicate between my service and the fragment. What I want is to communicate between my object which it has the `MediaPlayer` instance and my service.

Comment: where your creating the MediaPlayer object.you MediaPlayer object must be in activity or in fragment. so communicate through activity or fragment

Answer (score 0):

Create a public interface that allows you to communicate between your service and object.

```
public interface MyListener { 
         public void receiveNotification();
}
```

After that, you have to make your object implements that interface.

```
public class MediaObject implements MyListener {
public void init () {
     InitService.getService.addListener(this);
}

@Override
public void receiveNotification () {
       //what you want to do
}
//rest of your class
```

To make it work you should have in your service class sth like:

```
public class YourService extends Service  {
MyListener listener;
   public YourService static getService () {
         return YourService.this;
   }

   public void addListener (MyListener listener) {
         this.listener = listener;
   }
   public void methodYouWantToCommunicateWithObject () {
         //your code
         if (listener!= null) {
              listener.receiveNotification();

         }
   }
```

Comment: I had a problem with the static method `getService`. Android complains, `YourService.this` cannot be static. I ended up putting all the logic in my Service File. It is working now. Thanks anyway.